# How do I use ConstraintSet in Android to stack TextViews horizontally?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I've been looking around for a couple days now on how to add and constain TextViews programmatically, and for some reason I cannot get it to work. I've looked at other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43567429/7974544) and the recommended order in which you should go about adding constraints, however this did not work for me.

With my current solution, the TextViews stack up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP8gE.png). My aim was to have it seperated like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFGs5.png).

My current code looks like this:

```
// Get all the existing assignments and list them
Assignment[] currentAssignments = Assignment.getAssignments();
// Get the layout that will hold the assignments
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
// Loop through each assignment, creating a TextView and getting information for each one
for (int i = 0; i < currentAssignments.length; i++) {
    // Create new TextView and set properties
    TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
    newTextView.setId(i);
    newTextView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newTextView.setText(currentAssignments[i].getAssignmentName() + "\nHand in date: " + currentAssignments[i].getAssignmentHandInDate());
    newTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25);
    // Add to layout
    layout.addView(newTextView);
}
// Set up a new ConstraintSet so we can constrain all the assignments
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
// Clone the current layout
set.clone(layout);
// Loop through previously added assignments in layout and connect them
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    // Setup new constraints to place on screen properly
    if (i > 0) {
        // If assignment is not the first to be added, link it to the previously added assignment
        set.connect(i, ConstraintSet.TOP, i - 1, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);
    }
    else {
        // If the assignment is the first to be added link it to the top of the layout
        set.connect(i, ConstraintSet.TOP, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 8);
    }
}
// Apply changed layout to actual layout
set.applyTo(layout);
```

My question:

**How do I layout TextViews horizontally in a ConstraintLayout, programmatically?**

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Why are you doing this in Java code? Google does not even recommend creating `ConstraintLayout`-based layouts by editing the XML (they prefer that you use the GUI builder). If you are trying to show a collection of `Assignment` objects in a vertical list, use a `RecyclerView` or `ListView`, perhaps with a `ConstraintLayout` to define each row.

Comment: You know, @CommonsWare, I'd never considered not using ConstraintLayout. I think because it was the default layout, I just used it. The ListView sounds a lot better, I will give that a shot, thank you.